# Is it possible to create a custom formcontrol validation function which has dependencies for Reactive Forms

Tags: angular6

I have a Reactive form which has a ‘password’ and ‘verify password’ field. I want to create a custom validation function for ‘verify password’ field. It should check that the value of ‘verify password’ is same as ‘password’. Is it possible to create such a validation function and use it when create the form control?

‘formcontrol: [null, myValidationFunction]’

As far as I know, the validation function takes a ‘FormControl’ and returns an object. There is no way to pass another argument to it.

I have read that I could create a ‘Directive’ but the examples use it for ‘Template’ driven forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to put the password and verifyPassword into a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) of itself. This formGroup can then be passed to the custom validation function which takes an AbstractControl Type as an arugument from which the FormGroup extends. So you could go something like this :

### template.html

```
<form [formGroup]="main">
  <!-- Other FormControls -->
  <div formGroupName="passwordGroup">
    <!-- input element for password FormControl -->
    <!-- input element for verifyPassword FormControl -->
  </div>
</form>
```

### component.ts

```
function passwordValidator(c: AbstractControl) : {[key: string] : boolean} | null {
          let password = c.get('password'); 
          let verifyPassword = c.get('verifyPassword'); 
          if(password.value === verifyPassword.value)
            return null;
          else
            return {'match' : true};    
        }

ngOnInit() {
        this.main = this.fb.group({
            otherFormControls : [''],
            passwordGroup: this.fb.group({
            password: ['',[Validators.required],
            verifyPassword: ['',Validators.required]
            },{validator : passwordValidator})
});}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it would work but at the moment, I am struggling to get the nested form working. Could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051998/unable-to-create-a-nested-reactive-form

Comment: your solution works. I couldn't solve the nested form issue but as I have top-level form, I added the `passwordValidator` in the top level form. I'll try to solve the nested form issue but that isn't related to this. Thanks.