# unable to create a nested Reactive Form

Tags: angular6

The code/demo is at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jx7fdu

I am trying to create a nested Reactive Form. It is a simple signup form. It has `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `email`, `Password` and `VerifyPassword` Field. I have also created validators for the fields. The `html` also assigns `Bootstrap`'s `classes` depending on whether a field has errors or not.

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="validateField(signupForm,'firstName')" >
      <app-show-errors [control]="signupForm.controls.firstName"></app-show-errors>
```

`validateField` in `helper.service.ts` assigns `Bootstraps` `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes for visual representation. `app-show-errors` component gives texttual representation of the error.

For `verify password`, I want to check that its value is same as that of `password` field. To do this, I have clubbed them into a `FormGroup` and am passing that `FormGroup` to the validator function.

In `signup-component.component.ts`

```
    createForm(){ 
        this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
          firstName:[null,[Validators.required,this.helper.validateName]],           lastName:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/[A-Za-z]+/)]], 
          email:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.EMAIL_PATTERN)]], 
/*new group for password and verify password. Each of them should match the password criteria and the group should validate that the values of password and verify password is same*/
    passwordGroup:this.fb.group({
            password:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8),this.helper.validatePassword]],             confirmPassword:[null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8),this.helper.validatePassword]]
          },{validator:this.helper.confirmPasswordValidator})

        });
      }
```

Now my main issue is that I am unable to get the nested form (`passwordGroup`) working. I am seeing the following error in the console.

`ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`

`Example:`

`<div [formGroup]="myGroup">`
`<input formControlName="firstName">`
`</div>`

`In your class:`

`this.myGroup = new FormGroup({`
`firstName: new FormControl()`
 `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="passwordGroup">
```

into

```
<div class="form-group" formGroupName="passwordGroup">
```

Nested form groups use formGroupName

You can find more documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-nested-group)

Comment: thanks. I'll check. Your solution has solved the issue but I am stuck somewhere else now. I'll try to get the whole thing working.

Comment: If you're still stuck on your issue give me more informations

Comment: Thanks. The new error is `Cannot read property 'passwordGroup' of undefined`. You may check the Stackblitz link. I changed `<div class="form-group" formGroupName="passwordGroup">` to `<div  formGroupName="passwordGroup">`.

Comment: found the issue. `"validateField(signupForm,controls.passwordGroup,'password')" >` should have been `"validateField(signupForm.controls.passwordGroup,'password')" >`. a Type in `signupForm.controls`. I was doing `signupForm,controls`. Let me see if the code works now

Comment: So in summary, the top level form is a `FormGroup`, a control in a form is `FormControl` and as a control could be a `FormGroup`, such controls should have `FormGroupName` Directive instead of `FormControl` to tell Angular that this is a group (Angular should not treat it as a control) and the controls are actually inside this group.